# Screen record protection

Tags: android, screenshot

i use FLAG_SECURE to prevent the screeshot and the record screen, and this is good for external app but when i use the recrod screen native of android this not working.
How can prevent this?

Comment: "but when i use the recrod screen native of android this not working" -- what do you mean by "recrod screen native of android"?

Comment: in the actual android you can active screen record and dont is necesary use a external app i use android 9

Comment: That may be particular to your device. I am testing a Nexus 6P, and there is no sign of a built-in screenshot option.

Comment: a lot of device has this android create about 5.0 https://www.apptamin.com/blog/screen-recorder-for-android/

Comment: Everything on that page involves an external app. I have written apps that use the media projection APIs on Android 5.0+, and I have written extensively about `FLAG_SECURE`. I would be interested in trying to reproduce your findings, but your question does not provide enough detail for me to do so.

Comment: can you try this:
Huawei and Honor have screen recording baked into EMUI as well.
Like with OnePlus, you will find a screen recording (video camera icon) toggle in the Quick Settings menu when you pull down the notification shade.
You can also enable screen recording by pressing and holding the power button and the volume up key simultaneously.
Repeat either process to end screen recording.
https://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-record-your-screen-988008/

Comment: https://youtu.be/M_Ddwa_1aJ8  i do a vídeo and yo can ser de result and how i record screen

Comment: Presumably there is a bug in that device model. I wish that this was tested more closely by device manufacturers and Google. However, I do not think that there is anything that you can do about it.

Answer (score 1):

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    window.setFlags(
      WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
      WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
  }
}
```

That activity adds `FLAG_SECURE`. It blocks screenshots from "recrod screen native of android" on:

- A OnePlus E1005
- A Huawei KIW-L24
- A Google Pixel 2

In the case of the OnePlus and the Pixel, I used the system screenshot option available from the Power menu. In the case of the Huawei, I used the system screenshot option available from the notification shade. In all three cases, the device refused to take the screenshot.

`FLAG_SECURE` should block screenshots on all devices. If you are encounter problems with a particular device, the flaw is with the device, and there is nothing that you can do about it.

Comment: O use FLAG_SECURE and work for other app but no for narices récord